# COM and DirectSound

Tags: c++, directsound

I am trying to initialize Direct Sound the following way:

```
// Somewhere in my header...
#define DIRECT_SOUND_CREATE(name) HRESULT WINAPI name(LPCGUID pcGuidDevice, LPDIRECTSOUND *ppDS, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter)
typedef DIRECT_SOUND_CREATE(direct_sound_create);

// Initialization code...
HMODULE DSoundLib = LoadLibraryA("dsound.dll");
if(DSoundLib)
{
    direct_sound_create *DirectSoundCreate = (direct_sound_create*)
        GetProcAddress(DSoundLib, "DirectSoundCreate");

    LPDIRECTSOUND DirectSound;
    if(DirectSoundCreate && SUCCEEDED(DirectSoundCreate(0, &DirectSound,0)))
    {
```

The issue is that I am getting this error(?)

```
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(812)\combase.dll!75521B90: (caller: 7552093B) ReturnHr(1) tid(2444) 800401F0 CoInitialize has not been called.
```

Could anyone tell what this is/is related to? Do I need to call CoInitialize when using DirectSound or can I bypass COM stuff?

Here are my linker options:

```
set CommonLinkerFlags= -incremental:no -nodefaultlib -stack:0x100000,0x100000 ^
kernel32.lib ^
user32.lib ^
gdi32.lib ^
winmm.lib
```

Comment: `CoInitialize` is mandatory when dealing with COM stuff. And don't forget to call `CoUninitialize` when you done working with COM.

Comment: aha... And is there a way to use Direct Sound without COM? In handmade hero (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGC3xiliJW8), I didn't see any COM initializing code which seems weird...

Comment: There is no way to use Direct Sound without COM because it is COM-based. The very first call you make `DirectSoundCreate`, creates an instance of object implementing `IDirectSound` COM interface. Documentation mentions [that explicit COM initialization is not required in some situations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417554(v=vs.85).aspx). But it is a good idea to manually perform it anyway to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up! So CoInitialize seems the way to go. Write that up as an answer and I will accept it :3

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't be using ``DirectSound`` in a new project anyhow... Audio middleware engines and media players generally use WASAPI, and games should probably be using XAudio2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use Direct Sound without COM because it is COM-based. The very first call you make `DirectSoundCreate`, creates an instance of object implementing `IDirectSound` COM interface. Documentation mentions [that explicit COM initialization is not required in some situations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417554(v=vs.85).aspx). But it is a good idea to manually perform it anyway to be on the safe side. `CoInitialize` is mandatory when dealing with COM stuff. Typically this should be on of the first things to do at application initialization, before creating windows / renders. And don't forget to call `CoUninitialize` when you done working with COM.

Comment: One more question; if I have a custom implementation of the CRT (I implemented my own WinMainCRTStartup), should I call CoInitialize **before** calling WinMain ?

Comment: @MattMatt2000 Probably after so it can still work properly if you decide to switch to regular CRT.

Comment: Note that for DirectX programming in general, you should use ``CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED)`` in Win32 desktop applications. Note that for UWP and Xbox One apps when you initialize the Windows Runtime, COM is also initialized; and that when using C++/CX (``/ZW``) the Windows Runtime is already initialized by the CRT.